# GetActivity from IntentService in Android

Tags: android

I have an IntentService class

`public class eventoTimer extends IntentService {}`

```
public Utilities(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.session = new UserSessionManager(this.activity);
}
```

And I need to instantiate the Utilities class with an Activity but I do not know how to call the getActivity from the IntentService

Comment: public Utilities(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.session = new UserSessionManager(this.activity);
    }

Comment: Utilities u = new Utilities(getActivity());

Comment: IntentService has no ties to an activity. The solution is to implement it differently. Redesign your code

Answer (score 2):

> And I need to instantiate the Utilities class with an Activity but I do not know how to call the getActivity from the IntentService

You can't. For example, there is no requirement that there *be* an activity, as the user could have destroyed your activity while your `IntentService` is doing its work.

Either:

- Change `Utilities` to take a `Context`, rather than an `Activity` (so you can pass in the `IntentService` to the `Utilities` constructor), or
- Use an event bus (e.g., `LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus) to send a message to your activity, if it exists, to have it do something, or
- Get rid of the `IntentService`, if it is so tightly coupled to the activity, and do something else for your background threading (e.g., `AsyncTask`)